# Deleted entire harddisk. Now my laptop won't boot anything and stuck at grub rescue!

Tags: windows-7, grubrescue

My laptop is Dell Inspiron N4030. I used to use Ubuntu 12.04 and it was on the entire hard drive. I tried to install windows 7 but my laptop couldn't install it. So, I decided to delete the entire hard drive and do a fresh install of Windows 7. But after deletion I immediately removed the gparted live usb which I was using to delete the partitions of my hard drive. And then tried booting from windows 7 cd, didn't work, tried ubuntu live cd, didn't work, tried hiren's boot cd, didn't work, tried super grub disk, didn't work. Probably I'm not doing it right. Help needed badly.

Comment: Please update your question and provide some more information on what you mean by "didn't work". Did you receive an error, black screen, etc.?

Comment: Which information do I need to provide? It'd show a message - 
error: no such partition
grub rescue>

Comment: You say "And then tried booting from windows 7 cd, didn't work, tried ubuntu live cd, didn't work, tried hiren's boot cd, didn't work, tried super grub disk, didn't work." What do you mean it "didn't work"?

Comment: It'd always show the message - error: no such partition grub rescue>

Comment: you are booting from wrong device. press F9 to select correct boot device

Comment: Your boot device list key is F12. Press immediately when the Dell logo appears and select your DVD drive. [Source: Inspiron Setup Guide p. 61](https://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/insn4030/en/sg/sg_en.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting an error when trying to boot from the Ubuntu Live CD, it might be corrupted. You should create an Ubuntu Live USB, or another Live CD, and boot from that.

Comment: It wouldn't even boot from a freshly downloaded gparted live usb anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If it is throwing that error every time you try and boot from a CD, you aren't booting from the CD. Check your BIOS settings and make sure that you have your boot order correct. CD-ROM should be before hard drive. How you get to your BIOS settings varies between manufacturers and models of computers. It should say something about what key to press when you boot your computer, although it is typically DEL, ESC, F12, F10 or F2.

Comment: I've changed the order every time I booted.

Answer (score -1):

You can try installing fresh copy of the Ubuntu through network. Try configuring one system as server and then override your system to install a fresh copy. This can do the trick.